# How to export drop down list in laravel excel?

Tags: excel, laravel, laravel-excel

(Laravel 4) I save my excel file xls,xlsm or xlsx and I create dropdownlist vba and data validation.But when I open in laravel excel and save its deleted listbox and vba button.
Please help me